# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {...}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express, rest

I am trying to connect to the server and enter a username and password and then get the answer from the server. The answer consists of an object that also contains the information you see in the code. But after executing the code, I run into this error:

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Objects are not valid as a React child
> (found: object with keys {auth, token, user}). If you meant to render
> a collection of children, use an array instead.

what can I do?

`login.js`: (react app)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Login = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ username: "", password: "" });
  const [res, setRes] = useState('');

  const formHandler = (e) => {
    let newData = { ...data };
    newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setData(newData);
  };
  const clearData = () => setData({ username: "", password: "" });

  const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("/portfolio/login", {   ////////////Error points to this line
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) return res.json();
      })    //////////////////Error points to this line
      .then(JsonData => setRes(JsonData))
      .then(()=>{
        console.log(res);
        clearData()})
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  };

  return (
        <form
          onSubmit={(e) => login(e)}
          className="lg-form p-4 d-flex flex-column"
        >
          <input
            name="username"
            id="username"
            value={data.username}
            onChange={(e) => formHandler(e)}
            className="lg-input p-2 mb-4"
            type="name"
            placeholder="username"
          />
          <input
            name="password"
            id="password"
            value={data.password}
            onChange={(e) => formHandler(e)}
            className="lg-input p-2 mb-4"
            type="password"
            placeholder="password"
          />
          <button className="lg-btn px-4 py-2 mx-auto mb-4" type="submit">
            LOGIN
          </button>
        </form>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

`authenticayion.js`: (backend)

```
login(req, res) {
    //validation
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    
    this.model.admin.findOne(
      { username: req.body.username },
      async function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (user == null) return res.json({auth : false, message : "incorrect username"});
        else
          await bcrypt.compare(
            req.body.password,
            user.password,
            (err, result) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              if (!result) return res.json({auth : false, message : "incorrect password!"});
              if (result) {
                req.session.user = user;
                console.log(req.session.user);
                let payload = { user_id: user._id };
                let token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET, {
                  expiresIn: 300,
                });
                return res.json({auth : true, token : token, user});
              }
            }
          );
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error you have using the code you shared. It actually runs fine. But there is something wrong with your `login` function that is unrelated to the error you have, you are not supposed to use `async`/`await` and `then()` at the same time, it should be one or the other.

Comment: why do you initialize res state as empty string, but then set setRes to [JsonData] ?